# (Godot) Touch não realiza a animação do arco e não funciona corretamente

Tags: gdscript

Olá,

Sou um aluno de Multimédia e estou a trabalhar na minha Prova de Aptidão Profissional.

Para esta decidi criar um Jogo 2D RPG Zelda-like (para os dispositivos Android).
Para tal tenho utilizado a plataforma Godot que dá uso ao GDScript (Própria linguagem derivada do Python, otimizada para jogos).

Tenho toda uma interface de jogador criada, que tem alguns pequenos bugs.

Ao clicar no botão para disparar, o jogador deveria começar uma pequena animação e só depois a flecha seria criada, de momento, o jogador apenas dispara a flecha e salta a animação toda.

```
func get_attack_input():
if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_accept") and not charging_bow and can_shoot || attack and not charging_bow and can_shoot:
    charging_bow = true
    velocity = Vector2.ZERO
    sprite.play("Attack_Bow")
    tween.interpolate_property(self, "bow_power", 3, 8, 5, Tween.TRANS_LINEAR, Tween.EASE_IN_OUT)
    tween.start()
elif Input.is_action_just_released("ui_accept") and can_shoot || attack and can_shoot:
    charging_bow = false
    tween.stop(self, "bow_power")
    sprite.play("Idle")
    var arrow_instance = arrow.instance()
    var direction = -1 if sprite.flip_h else 1
    arrow_instance.init(direction, bow_power)
    get_parent().add_child(arrow_instance)
    arrow_instance.global_position = global_position
    arrow_instance.global_position.x += 16 * direction
    bow_power = 0
    print("Shoot")
    
    #Optimize Arrow
    if get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("arrows").size() >= 3:
        for arrow in get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("arrows"):
            arrow.queue_free()
            print("deleted arrows")

    #Disable Shoot
    can_shoot = false
    
    #Start Timer
    timer.start()
```

Comment: Não conheço muito o Python ou o Godot Engine, mas não está faltando uma identação em todas as linhas após a definiçao da função (primeira linha)?

Comment: de onde vc tirou a função `get_tree()`?

Comment: Reverti a pergunta para a versão original e alterei a tag para [tag:Godot]

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa usar a função yield para o codigo só continuar quando a animação terminar para que não haja saltos, você pode encontrar na documentação da godot.

seu code ficaria assim

```
func get_attack_input():
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_accept") and not charging_bow and can_shoot | attack and not charging_bow and can_shoot:
        charging_bow = true
        velocity = Vector2.ZERO
        sprite.play("Attack_Bow")
        yield($sprite,"animation_finished") ##### AQUI AQUI AQUI AQUI 
        tween.interpolate_property(self, "bow_power", 3, 8, 5, Tween.TRANS_LINEAR, Tween.EASE_IN_OUT)
        tween.start()
    elif Input.is_action_just_released("ui_accept") and can_shoot | attack and can_shoot:
        charging_bow = false
        tween.stop(self, "bow_power")
        sprite.play("Idle")
        arrow_instance = arrow.instance()
        direction = -1 if sprite.flip_h else 1
        arrow_instance.init(direction, bow_power)
        get_parent().add_child(arrow_instance)
        arrow_instance.global_position = global_position
        arrow_instance.global_position.x += 16 * direction
        bow_power = 0
        print("Shoot")


#Optimize Arrow
if get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("arrows").size()>=3:
    for arrow in get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("arrows"):
        arrow.queue_free()
        print("deleted arrows")

#Disable Shoot
can_shoot = false

#Start Timer
timer.start()
```

Você pode ver mais sobre a função yield na propia documentação https://docs.godotengine.org/pt_BR/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html

Comment: Obrigado por tentar ajudar, infelizmente a pergunta estava marcada errada e NÃO se trata de um problema de linguagem Python, **o problema é de linguagem Godot Engine**. Por esse motivo vale a pena você verificar se sua resposta esta de acordo com o problema apresentado. =D

Comment: @IcaroMartins arrumando o "def" e os ( ) nos `if` até talvez fique um código válido de Godot Engine. Pode ter sido só "força de hábito" :)

Comment: Eu errei por colocar def ao inves de func mas o código funciona, eu vou editar e colocar as referencas,